# Mono Connection string

Tags: sqlite, mono, connection-string

I am trying to connect to an Sqlite db from my mono app but I keep getting this error when trying to open the connection.

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in the correct format
```

Here is my connection string:

```
String connString = @"Data Source=C:\Users\pc_user\Desktop\Folder\Database.db;Version=2.2;Password=xxx;";
```

**I managed to connect to my db(after countless man-hours) but now I can't insert records into it.I get this ambiguous error:**

```
System.ArgumentException: element already exists
```

Help,anyone

Comment: Wasn't there an `SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder` class?

Comment: I haven't used SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder.This is my first app,Am new to this.How should I construct the class?

Comment: I cannot try or check the manuals right now, but from memory I think you should simply call `new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder()`, then assign something to the `DataSource` and the `Password` (?) properties, and then the ready-made connection string is ready in the `ConnectionString` property.

Comment: I tried using the SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder but I now get this error: 

`System.DllNotFoundException: System.Data.SQLite.DLL`

I have referenced the DLL correctly,it puzzling.

Comment: Here is my `SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder` code:

`SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder b = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder();`
            `b.DataSource = @"C:/Users/pc_user/Desktop/Folder/Database.db";`
            `b.Password = "xxx";`
            `b.Version = 3;`

Comment: Hmm, the `DllNotFoundException` cannot really come from the way you use the connection builder; when does it occur? Is the DLL copied into the output directory while compiling?

Comment: I also think it has nothing to do with the connection builder.The error arises when I try to open the connection.There is this persistent warning regarding my platform(mismatch between the platform and the DLL type,the DLL is x86).I tried changing the degug platform to target x86 but that did not work.

Comment: Ah right, that problem again ... then something that you're launching, or something that is launched by the debug platform, is still targetting "any CPU" while you are using an x64 system, I presume.

Comment: I've changed the options in the configuration manager to x86 and checked settings in the project properties to make sure the target is x86 but the warning is still there.Is there any other setting for 'any CPU' that I might have missed?

Comment: Just if there are any other projects around.

Comment: There is one more project in the solution,a WCF project.But that too is set to x86.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Connectionstring.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite) (an invaluable resource): The "Version" key can take value "2" for SQLite 2.x (default) or value "3" for SQLite 3.x

Have you tried

```
String connString = @"Data Source=C:\Users\pc_user\Desktop\Folder\Database.db;Version=2.2;Password=xxx;";
```

Answer (score 0):

Fishcake is right : you should set Version to either 2 or 3.

Could you try changing your connection string to:

```
    String connString = @"Data Source=file:C:\Users\pc_user\Desktop\Folder\Database.db;Version=2;Password=xxx;"
```

(the change is to add "file:" after data source).
If it doesn't work, can you try with

```
    String connString = @"URI=file:C:\Users\pc_user\Desktop\Folder\Database.db;Version=2;Password=xxx;"
```

And, you keep having the same error, could you try with a password-less database (and removing the **Password=** from your connection string)?